# How to get select value from another php file?

Tags: php, forms

How to get `<select>` value from another php file. 
Example :

index.php

```
$text = $_POST['text']
<select id="text">
    <option> text 1</option>
    <option> text 2</option>
    <option> text 3</option>
</select>
```

data.php

```
$sql= "SELECT column FROM table where $text='text 1'"
```

as you can read above, how to get value from `$text` in `index.php` and use it in `data.php`

Comment: does index.php have a proper form; with an action of data.php? Also the options are missing values

Comment: @nogad i have try your solution, undefined index : text on data.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only forgot to add value for options itself

```
<form method="post" action="data.php">    
    <select name="text" id="text">
        <option value="text 1"> text 1</option>
        <option value="text 1"> text 2</option>
        <option value="text 1"> text 3</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit the form"/>
</form>
```

then add `$_GET` on your data.php

```
$text = $_GET['text']
$sql= "SELECT column FROM table where $text='ABCDE'"
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try

Comment: i have try your solution, undefined index : text on data.php

Comment: your form uses POST not GET

Comment: You should include this on your index.php `if(isset($_POST['text'])){
 $text=$_POST['text'];
}`

Answer (score 0):

hi you can passe this value with post method 
in index.php

```
 <form action="url_to_data.php" method="post">
        <select name="text">
           <option> text 1</option>
           <option> text 2</option>
           <option> text 3</option>
        </select>
      <button>submit<button>
    </form>
```

in data.php

```
<?php 
   $text = $_POST['text'];
   echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: i have try your solution, undefined index : text on data.php